# How to combine FlatList and if?

Tags: javascript, react-native

If the 'unit' value under data(dokuzuncu) equals the condition, I want to redirect it to a different page. I want to redirect it to different pages according to the bold text in the screenshot.Can you help me where is the error in my code?
[image]

```js
import data from './data/dokuzuncu'

export default class dokuz extends React.Component {
    renderContactsItems = ({item,index}) => {
        return(
            <View style={styles.list}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>  {
                    if (data.unit === 'Madde ve Özellikleri') {
                        const pushAction = StackActions.push('tyt');
                        this.props.navigation.dispatch(pushAction);
                      }
                    else if (data.unit === 'Hareket ve Kuvvet') {
                        const pushAction = StackActions.push('tyt');
                        this.props.navigation.dispatch(pushAction);
                      }
                    else if (data.unit === 'Enerji') {
                        const pushAction = StackActions.push('tyt');
                        this.props.navigation.dispatch(pushAction);
                      }
                    else if (data.unit === 'Isı ve Sıcaklık') {
                        const pushAction = StackActions.push('tyt');
                        this.props.navigation.dispatch(pushAction);
                      }
                    else if (data.unit === 'Elektrostatik') {
                        const pushAction = StackActions.push('tyt');
                        this.props.navigation.dispatch(pushAction);
                      }
                  }}
                >
                    <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:25}}>{item.unit}</Text>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:25}}>{item._id}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
                renderItem={this.renderContactsItems}
                data={data}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean `item.unit`?

Comment: onPress={() =>  {
                    if (data.unit === 'Madde ve Özellikleri') {
                        const pushAction = StackActions.push('tyt');
                        this.props.navigation.dispatch(pushAction);
                      } 
According to this code, if the value under item.unit is equal to the value I wrote, I want it to redirect to a different page.

Comment: Right, but `<Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:25}}>{item.unit}</Text>` there it uses item.unit.

Comment: `if (item.unit === ...)`.  item.unit.  Not data.unit.

Comment: what is `StackActions`? an Array? because [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) only returns the current Array length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if (item.unit === ...). item.unit. Not data.unit. – James thank you.